# How to find the CPU memory utilization of a Windows 2008 server

Tags: windows

We have an issue with sharepoint was running slow on yesterday. Now to troubleshoot this, i would like to know the CPU utilization for yesterday(for example from 10AM to 12AM) on the server. How to get this report.

Thanks in advance. 
Sivakumar. P

Comment: You'll need to setup a *performance log* for CPU utilization (check builtin Windows help). Once you set it up, you can check the log. Note that *performance log* **will** decrease your overall system performance, albeit very small.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  That information isn't recorded unless you record it, so that information does not exist anymore.

If you want to set it up going forward, you do it through `Computer Management` -> `Performance` -> `Data Collector Sets`.  As mentioned, collecting this information will increase the serve load slightly (and consume disk space), but once setup, you can then access historical data under the `Reports` section.

Real time data can be monitored with `Performance Monitor` (`perfmon.exe`), also found in the `Performance` sections of `Computer Management`, under `Monitoring Tools`.

Answer (score 1):

As Jay already said one way to do this is setting up a performance log.

The easiest way to get there is entering `perfmon` or `perfmon.msc` in your command line or execute dialog (Windows key + R)

There you can set up a new log (protocols item in the tree view) and select the items you want to log and the interval of how often they are supposed to be logged - as well as the output format of your log. And of course the time span the log shall be conducted.

Saving it as comma separated values has the advantage of being easily restructured in a table using Excel or similar programs

Answer (score -1):

google "logman.exe" for command-line friendly ways to go about this on multiple servers.